# Box model properties on anonymous inline boxes

Tags: css

From CSS [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-boxes)

> Any text that is directly contained inside a block container element
>   (not inside an inline element) must be treated as an anonymous inline
>   element.
>
> In a document with HTML markup like this:

```
<p>Some <em>emphasized</em> text</p>
```

> the `<p>` generates a block box, with several inline boxes inside it.
>   The box for "emphasized" is an inline box generated by an inline
>   element (`<em>`), but the other boxes ("Some" and "text") are inline
>   boxes generated by a block-level element (`<p>`). The latter are called
>   anonymous inline boxes, because they do not have an associated
>   inline-level element.

Now, my query is simple. Can I have margins, paddings , border set by CSS on these anonymous inline boxes ?

Consider the image below:
[image]

We see there are line boxes also. Can we apply the same margin, padding and border on these line boxes too ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; since margins, borders and padding are not inherited properties, and you cannot style anonymous boxes directly with CSS (not even with the universal selector, or pseudo-elements), anonymous inline boxes cannot have margins, borders or padding.

Line boxes cannot have margins, borders or padding either.